# What is the process when I install react package?

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm looking into the [react](https://github.com/facebook/react) package. Looking and understanding the directories of react repository, I have some questions and I failed to find the proper answers.

So, I have several questions.

1. What makes The **A. react package in git repository** to be **B. installed react package**

**A. react package in git repository**

```
react(called root directory)
 |
 --packages(called workspace)
   |
   --react
      |
      --npm
      |
      --src
      |
      --index.js
...
```

**B. installed react package** (by yarn add react)

```
node_modules
 |
 --react
    |
    --cjs
    |
    --umd
    |
    --index.js
...
```

2. The react package is in `packages/`(workspace) directory and there are other packages also. I found that we call it **monorepo**. So, if I want to make **monorepo**, do I need to publish(publishing npm package) all packages in `packages/`? (i.e. in `packages/react`, do `yarn publish` and also in `packages/react-dom` and so on)
3. If each directory in `packages/` is npm package, what is the functionality of `scripts` in **root directory**?

Comment: The question is very confusing, are you having problem or just trying to understand how they work?
What do you mean with
''and following directories are removed

    npm
    src''
from where?

Comment: @btnhawk sorry for my question. yes. I just trying to understanding the process of installing react. The above example is that the **npm**and **src** directories are in react git repository but when I install react app, those are removed and **cjs** and **umd** directories appear.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a confusing question but I hope I can answer at least some of your questions,

- The react git repo contains all the files necessary to use reactJS. This includes things like the Component structure, the JSX interpreter and more. There is great documentation about the react library.
- The react package is installed to your computer when you run the command `npm install react`, this will automatically install react into your package.json file.
- Your package.json file contains all the dependencies and packages that your project needs. The package.json file is always included in a react project, but the actual .node_modules folder is typically ignored via the .gitignore file. If you need to download the files of a package.json file, simply navigate to the directory and use the command `npm install`, this will download all the packages listed.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, but hopefully it helps!